# How can I reuse this code to create multiple buttons at run time?

Tags: vba, button, ms-word, controls

I want to have multiple simple buttons in my document when it loads:

- Add Patient details
- Add history
- Print note
- Save note

I know the VBA I want to attach to each one of those buttons. But how do I use the code here to make these multiple buttons and assign events to them?

```
`Sub Test()
'Add a command button to a new document
Dim doc As Word.Document
Dim shp As Word.InlineShape
Set doc = ActiveDocument

Set shp = doc.Content.InlineShapes.AddOLEControl(ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1")
shp.OLEFormat.Object.Caption = "Click Here"

'Add a procedure for the click event of the inlineshape
'**Note: The click event resides in the This Document module
Dim sCode As String
sCode = "Private Sub " & shp.OLEFormat.Object.Name & "_Click()" & vbCrLf & _
        "   MsgBox ""You Clicked the CommandButton""" & vbCrLf & _
        "End Sub"
doc.VBProject.VBComponents("ThisDocument").CodeModule.AddFromString sCode

End Sub`
```

Comment: Why are you using code to add the buttons? This will create a security nightmare for anyone who has to use it. A better approach is to put the buttons into the document template so that they are already there when a new document is created.

Comment: I will be using this on my local computer. The code actually comes from a page by microsoft, but it is very cumbersome to use.

Thanks for the suggestion regarding the template. That was the fall back plan, but then I would need to do a few extra steps on my computer and my assistant's computer, and any shared computers I might work on - I was hoping I could just copy paste the entire VBA code into every computer.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/add-button-in-word

Comment: Using a document template should not be a “fall back plan”. That should be your default starting point. Every document you create is based on a template, and remains linked to it. Any code required should be in the template. This makes sharing the template much simpler as it can be stored in a network folder. And by template I mean a file saved as a Word template with a .dotx or .dotm extension.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I am trying to "walk" backwards... So does the template store all the controls (buttons in this case) and macros?

Comment: "does the template store all the controls (buttons in this case) and macros?" - Yes. The code, and any quick parts/building blocks, stays in the template when you create a new document, but everything else gets promoted into the document.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using ribbon controls instead. If you deal with open XML documents in Word you can insert the ribbon XML markup inside the document and just have event handlers in VBA. You just need to edit the source Office (Word in your case) file.

You can read more about ribbon XML markup in the following articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: Thank you, will look into it. However, as described above, this seems to be very difficult to get done, especially on shared computers.